# Why did my Kymko 50cc Agility Scooter suddenly stop running?

Tags: rough-idle, scooter

I have a brand new Kymco 50cc scooter and all of a sudden it won't stay running. I found 3 hoses that go nowhere, is this normal? I think my ex cut the hoses...hope I'm wrong!

[image]

Comment: Photos of the hoses showing where they come from would be quite helpful. It's extremely common for there to be at least one hose coming from the fuel tank, to near the ground just left dangling, that's the drain for the fuel cap, and meant to go nowhere.

Comment: only I don't know how to add pics!? I'm sorry

Comment: I tried adding a pic to the main post, but don't think it will work. Can I send to an email address?? I really appreciate the help. I'm all alone out here!

Comment: Try using the editing interface to add an image from file: click on the small icon looking like a mountain in a frame.

Comment: Even if you save the photo to PhotoBucket or the like and just edit in the address, we can make it work for you.

Comment: Welcome Lisa Jo! It's nice to meet you. It looks like you did a great job getting a picture in. As Paulster2 said, there's always someone around who can download from someplace else, just in case. There's a post [here](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/766/) that has a few options of how to do it. Please know that I'm not advertising my own contribution, it's just something I added to others in an effort to be helpful!

Comment: I submitted an edit to change your post a little. If accepted, you'll see that the title has a little more detail, and I put the text about the picture. For me, it's easier to read if the words are the first thing. Please feel free to reject that edit if I've done something I shouldn't. Thanks, and I really hope you stay and have some fun here!

Answer (score 1):

**Those hoses are supposed to be that way**

Most scooters and motorcycles have a few hoses for venting of various gasses coming out the bottom of the motorcycle/scooter behind the motor.  Possible uses for these hoses include the following:

- Gas Tank Ventilation
- Carbon Filter emissions control ventilation
- Float bowl overflow for carbureted vehicles
- Airbox water drain hose.

Those hoses weren't sabotaged by someone.  You have another issue with your vehicle.

If you ask another question and state all of your symptoms someone can hopefully assist you diagnosing and troubleshooting your vehicle to get it running again.

Good luck.

Comment: To add another one: It's still common that small scooter batteries are not sealed. In this case, they also often have a hose to vent gas (and liquid), which leads down to the road. At least my scooter has this. (I don't want hydrogen to accumulate under my seat...)